# Eliminar duplicados de una variable pero eliminando las filas que cumplan una condicion

Tags: r

quisiera eliminar la filas repetidas de una variable, pero cumplan con una condición jerárquica en base a otra variable de tipo factor, me explico

Supongamos que tengo un df de la siguiente forma:

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4),
                  nivel = c("a", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "c", "b", "d", "f", "a", "d", "b"))
```

[image: img1]

La salida que me gustaría obtener, es la siguiente:

[image: img2]

Es decir, que exista un id único, pero el nivel que quede junto al id, sea alguno que se defina,
para ello utilizo la función reorder.factor y asigno los niveles a,b,c,d,e,f (en ese orden) pero una vez ordenados los niveles de esa variable de tipo factor no se como eliminar los duplicados en base a esa condicion, se me ocurre utilizar la funcion slice o top_n pero no se de que manera seria la adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que encontré la solución a lo que buscas

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4),
              nivel = c("a", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "c", "b", "d", "f", "a", "d", "b"))

 data$nivel<-ordered(data$nivel, levels = c("f", "e", "d","c","b","a"))

 data_ordendad<-data %>% group_by(id) %>%
                summarise(nivel=max(nivel))


 # A tibble: 6 x 2
   id nivel
 <dbl> <ord>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 a    
4     4 b    
5     5 e    
6     6 f
```

Lo que se realiza mas que filtrar es agrupar por el id y quedarnos con los valores máximos asignados en los factores cuando agrupamos la información por id , espero te funcione

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono, una ultima consulta, si tuviera mas variables, y aplico ese código, perdería la información de las variables restantes, como podría solucionar eso?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es el valor mínimo por `id`, esto en R base es una agrupación:

```
aggregate(nivel ~ id, data, min)

  id nivel
1  1     a
2  2     b
3  3     a
4  4     b
5  5     e
6  6     f
```

agrupamos por `id` y aplicamos la función `min()`  a `nivel`.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono, una ultima consulta, si tuviera mas variables, y aplico ese código, perdería la información de las variables restantes, como podría solucionar eso?

Comment: Simplemente debes ajustar la formula de agrupamiento para considerar las nuevas variables, ya sea como agrupación, o como función de agregación